# Android app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio not working within ScrollView->LinearLayout container

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I am trying to create a square LinearLayout container of id `imgContainer` within a ScrollView element, but I am unable to do so because the `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio` doesn't seem to be working. Using the following xml code, the `imgContainer` renders with a height of 0dp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/imgContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/trackName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Test Name"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgContainer" />

              <!-- Other stuff -->

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

However, when I move the `imgContainer` out of the ScrollView like so, the `imgContainer` is square-shaped as expected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/imgContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

     <ScrollView
        ...>
        <!-- Same as above -->
     </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I also tried moving out of the LinearLayout it is nested in while still having it within the ScrollView, but that didn't work either. If anyone knows how to fix this, and why this happens, that would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This just isn't how view groups work I'm afraid. Each view group only lays out it's direct children, so using constraint layout attributes on children of a linear layout doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. I guess I'll try to find another way.

Comment: With `ConstraintLayout` you generally don't need any other view groups at all. The whole point of it is to be powerful enough to layout children in a more complex manner. Here you should only need `ScrollView -> ConstraintLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

app:layout_constraint..   only work under  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

you can try the following:

```
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/imgContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trackName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Test Name"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgContainer" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```